# Pagedown(markdown editor) with Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, text-editor, markdown

I trying to use the [pagedown(markdown editor)](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/), the one that stackoverflow in my django based website. However to get the markdown editor in a textarea it is required to give the text area both id and class as

```
<textarea id="wmd-input" class="wmd-input"/>
```

However the form fields generated by django have a default id as `id_<field-name>`. Is there a way I can assign the same id to this text_area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can directly pass id as well in the models.py where your are passing class name. This will override the default behavior.

```
widgets = {
        '<attribute_name>': Textarea(attrs={'class':'wmd-input','id':'wmd-input'}),
            }
```